# How is the resistor value for boost conversion calculated?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, battery-charging

I'm looking at [MCP1640](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002234C.pdf) and in Section 5.2, an equation for calculating RTOP is presented. However, the two examples underneath have RBOT = 309kOhm. How did that come about? Is 309kOhm some standard value? Without fixing a value for RBOT, one could only derive a ratio between RBOT and RTOP.

The second circuit on page 2 uses RBOT = 562kOhm though. Is RBOT meant to be arbitrary?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to choose \$R_\mathrm{BOT}\$ such that

(a) you can find close-enough standard resistor values for both \$R_\mathrm{BOT}\$  and \$R_\mathrm{TOP}\$, and

(b) \$R_\mathrm{BOT}\$ and \$R_\mathrm{TOP}\$ are the right order of magnitude.

About the order of magnitude, cf. the explanation on section 5.2:

> There are some potential issues with higher value resistors. For small surface mount resistors, environment contamination can create leakage paths that significantly change the resistor divider ratio and modify the output voltage tolerance.
>
> Smaller feedback resistor values will increase the current drained from the battery by a few μA, but will result in good regulation over the entire temperature range and environment conditions.

So if you pick 1 K or 10 K resistors instead of 100 K resistors you will have a bit more current drain* but it will otherwise work fine. If you pick 1 M resistors or more, you may have issues with noise and stability.

They mention contaminants: moisture and dirt on the PCB can create parasitic resistors of some 10s or 100s of MOhms. You want your divider network to be lower than that so that it "wins" over these parasitic current paths.

* estimate it as \$I_\mathrm{drain}=\frac{V_\mathrm{out}}{R_\mathrm{BOT}+R_\mathrm{TOP}}\$

Answer (score 1):

The value of the resistors is arbitrary within some limits, and you're right: their ratio is the important factor as that determines the output voltage.

Section 5.2 in the data sheet PDF tells you the points to observe:

> There are some potential issues with higher value resistors. For small
>   surface mount resistors, environment contamination can create leakage
>   paths that significantly change the resistor divider ratio and modify
>   the output voltage tolerance.
>
> Smaller feedback resistor values will increase the current drained
>   from the battery by a few μA, but will result in good regulation over
>   the entire temperature range and environment conditions. The feedback
>   input leakage current can also impact the divider and change the
>   output voltage tolerance.

Using values within the range the data sheet shows as examples is usually the safe way to go.

309kohms is an [E96](http://www.logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html) value, you may use a different value from the more common E24 series if that's a problem for you.